# change JavaFX MediaPlayer playback speed

Tags: java, javafx, media-player

I'm trying to slow down the playback speed using JavaFX MediaPlayer `javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer`

is there any way to modify playback speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MediaPlayer` has a [rate property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#rateProperty):

```
mediaPlayer.setRate(...);
```

Comment: it worked thank you! however, it seems that adjusting the speed affects the pitch of the sound, is there anyway to maintain the same pitch to not being dropped?